# No handlers could be found for logger "elasticsearch.trace"

Tags: python, django, pyelasticsearch

Updated:
Turns out, this is not a function of cron.  I get the same behavior when running the script from the command line, if it in fact has a record to process and communicates with ElasticSearch.

---

I have a cron job that runs a python script which uses `pyelasticsearch` to index some documents in an ElasticSearch instance.  The script works fine from the command line, but when run via cron, it results in this error:

> No handlers could be found for logger "elasticsearch.trace"

Clearly there's some logging configuration issue that only crops up when run under cron, but I'm not clear what it is.   Any insight?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this by explicitly configuring a handler for the `elasticsearch.trace` logger, as I saw in [examples](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/da1a8b92c9827e0edd0cea5a67f07ada8e9237a0/example/load.py#L169) from the pyelasticsearch repo.

After importing pyelasticsearch, set up a handler like so:

```
tracer = logging.getLogger('elasticsearch.trace')
tracer.setLevel(logging.INFO)
tracer.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('/tmp/es_trace.log'))
```

I'm not interested in keeping the trace logs, so I used the near-at-hand Django `NullHandler`.

```
from django.utils.log import NullHandler
tracer = logging.getLogger('elasticsearch.trace')
tracer.setLevel(logging.INFO)
tracer.addHandler(NullHandler())
```

Comment: It's worth noting that, best I can tell, the "no handlers could be found" messages are just for information.  They don't indicate a problem.